# Get index value of list on condition in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have string list like,

```
list[0]="want"
list[1]="to"
list[2]="create"
list[3]="user"
list[4]="account"
```

I need to take the "user" string's index value. i.e, 3. I tried this way,

```
list.Where(o => o.Contains("user")).ToList();
```

I know it won't return the index position. How can I achieve this? Anyhelp?

Comment: `int idx = list.IndexOf("user");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to get the index of an existing string that you know completely use:

```
int index = list.IndexOf("user");
```

If the string only *contains* `"user"` but may be a bigger string that you don't have:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(item => item.Contains("user"));
```

In both cases, if `index` is 0 or greater you have the index and a negative value signals that the item was not found.

Comment: This is good, but I just want to point out that if you use the `FindIndex` version, if there is more than one element that contains "user", it will return the index of the first element only. It's hard to tell from the question/example whether that would be a problem or not.

Comment: Same with `IndexOf`.